# How to linked OpenCV 3.4.5 dnn module with custom cv_bridge using catkin? Error: undefined reference cv::dnn:experimental_dnn_v2::Net::Net()

Tags: opencv, compiler-errors, compilation, ros, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to use publisher-subcriber no to run my object recognition program by streaming images from my webcam. In my program, I am using readNetFromTensorflow function that provided by opencv_dnn library. But while I catkin_make on my workspace, there is always popup this error:

```
CMakeFiles/my_subscriber.dir/src/my_subscriber.cpp.o: In function `main':
my_subscriber.cpp:(.text+0x2ee): undefined reference to `cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v2::readNetFromTensorflow(cv::String const&, cv::String const&)'
my_subscriber.cpp:(.text+0x30e): undefined reference to `cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v2::Net::setPreferableBackend(int)'
my_subscriber.cpp:(.text+0x31a): undefined reference to `cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v2::Net::setPreferableTarget(int)'
my_subscriber.cpp:(.text+0x4c4): undefined reference to `cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v2::Net::~Net()'
my_subscriber.cpp:(.text+0x5f0): undefined reference to `cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v2::Net::~Net()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
image_transport_tutorial/CMakeFiles/my_subscriber.dir/build.make:176: recipe for target '/home/odroid/image_transport_ws/devel/lib/image_transport_tutorial/my_subscriber' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/odroid/image_transport_ws/devel/lib/image_transport_tutorial/my_subscriber] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1125: recipe for target 'image_transport_tutorial/CMakeFiles/my_subscriber.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [image_transport_tutorial/CMakeFiles/my_subscriber.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

And here is my program so far:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>

#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

const size_t inWidth = 320;
const size_t inHeight = 320;
const char* classNames[] = {"background",
                            "A", "B", "C"};
cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
int h,w;

void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{

  try
  {
    cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);
    w = cv_ptr->image.cols;
    h = cv_ptr->image.rows;



    cv::waitKey(10);
  }
  catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Could not convert from '%s' to 'bgr8'.", msg->encoding.c_str());
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "image_listener");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  cv::namedWindow("view");
  cv::startWindowThread();
  image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
  //! [Initialize network]
  cv::dnn::Net net = dnn::readNetFromTensorflow("/home/odroid/Desktop/Archive/frozen_inference_graph.pb","/home/odroid/Desktop/Archive/graph.pbtxt");
  net.setPreferableBackend(3);
  net.setPreferableTarget(1);
  //! [Initialize network]

  image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("camera/image", 1, &imageCallback);
  //cv::Mat inputBlob = cv::dnn::blobFromImage(cv_ptr->image,1.0, Size(inWidth,inHeight),Scalar(127.5,127.5,127.5), true,false); //Convert Mat to batch of images

  //net.setInput(inputBlob);
  //Mat detection = net.forward();

  ros::spin();
  cv::destroyWindow("view");
}
```

If I comment cv::dnn::Net, I can build 100% complete.

And here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

#Enable C++11
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)


project(image_transport_tutorial)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS cv_bridge image_transport message_generation sensor_msgs)

# add the resized image message
add_message_files(DIRECTORY msg
   FILES ResizedImage.msg
)
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES sensor_msgs)

catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS cv_bridge image_transport message_runtime sensor_msgs)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
#Set OpenCV
set(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS /usr/local/include/ /usr/local/include/opencv2/)


#Print some message showing some of them
message(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")
message(STATUS "config: ${OpenCV_DIR}")
message(STATUS "version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}")
message(STATUS "include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# add the publisher example
add_executable(my_publisher src/my_publisher.cpp)
add_dependencies(my_publisher ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(my_publisher ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})

# add the subscriber example
add_executable(my_subscriber src/my_subscriber.cpp)
add_dependencies(my_subscriber ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(my_subscriber ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})

# add the plugin example
add_library(resized_publisher src/manifest.cpp src/resized_publisher.cpp src/resized_subscriber.cpp)
add_dependencies(resized_publisher ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(resized_publisher ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})


# Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
install(TARGETS my_publisher my_subscriber resized_publisher
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(DIRECTORY launch/
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/launch
)

install(DIRECTORY model/
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/model
)

install(FILES resized_plugins.xml
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)
```

**

> UPDATES:

**

If I catkin_make by using opencv 3.3.1, which is built while I installed ROS Kinetic, I can compiled it 100% successful. But when I do some rosrun, it will cause some error. Here is the error:

```
Preprocessor/sub:Sub(Preprocessor/mul)(Preprocessor/sub/y) OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (Unknown layer type Sub in op Preprocessor/sub) in populateNet, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp, line 1311
```

I have done some browsing for a few days and found a guy that saying it's because of cv_bridge and image_transport of the opencv that comes with ROS.Here the link:https://answers.ros.org/question/318146/using-opencv-dnn-module-with-ros/

Please help me, Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this issue, here the solution:

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws
$ git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv src/vision_opencv
$ git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/image_transport_plugins.git src/image_transport_plugins
$ catkin_make
```

Mantap!